# Is it possible to unite Reducer's ActionCreators?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I was thinking of joining some "`on()`" which do exactly the same thing, thus saving lines of code, is this possible?

Giving an example of my code:

```
const peopleReducer = createReducer(
    INIT_STATE,
    on(fromPeopleAction.GET_ALL_SUCCESS, (state, { peoples }) => adapter.addMany(peoples, { ...state, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.GET_ALL_FAIL, (state, { error }) => ({ ...state, error, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.CREATE_SUCCESS, (state, { people }) => adapter.addOne(people, { ...state, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.CREATE_FAIL, (state, { error }) => ({ ...state, error, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.DELETE_SUCCESS, (state, { id }) => adapter.removeOne(id, { ...state, loading: false })),
    on(fromPeopleAction.DELETE_FAIL, (state, { error }) => ({ ...state, error, loading: false }))
);
```

Note that we have some "`on()`" which do the same thing, is it possible to call multiple actions for the same `on()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by [*`on`'s overloads*](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/reducer_creator.ts#L14-L78), I think you can use the same logic for multiple actions if you do this:

```js
on(action1, action2, action3, ...action10, (state, action) => {})
```

Note that after [10 actions](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/reducer_creator.ts#L165), you'll *lose the types*.

It's also important to notice that the **last argument** should be the **reducer**.